# Issue with re.sub in Python3 and not in Python2

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I've got an old script in Python 2.7 that runs a re.sub process correctly. However when I try to use it in Python 3 I get `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

The relevant code is

```
substitution_array=[
    [r"^Map From GroupLayer","Add Map GroupLayer"],[r"^Map From","Add Map Auto Layer"]
    ,[r"^\s+Papersize\s+.*",""],[r"^Set Window.*",""],[r"^Open Window.*",""]]

for row in substitution_array:
        print(row[0])
        for x in newfile:
          line = re.sub(row[0],row[1],x)
          line2=filter(line.strip, line)
          newfile2.append(line2)
        print ("Finished: "+row[0])
        newfile=newfile2
        newfile2=[]
```

I get the following output

```
G:\GIS_Tables\Vector_Data\Administrative\Cadastre\Road_Reserves>python3 Create_MB_from_WOR.py
--- Table Name: Road_Reserves
^Map From GroupLayer
Finished: ^Map From GroupLayer
^Map From
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Create_MB_from_WOR.py", line 43, in <module>
    line = re.sub(row[0],row[1],x)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\lib\re.py", line 192, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

So it is failing on `,[r"^Map From","Add Map Auto Layer"]` and when I delete this it fails on the next one as well.

I had a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html and think that I have escaped things correctly but what's wrong here?

Here's the same code running on the same data in Python 2.7 correctly
[image]

Comment: `r"^\\s+Papersize\\s+.*"` should be `r"^\s+Papersize\s+.*"`, *without* the double slashes. You shouldn't double-escape in raw strings.

Comment: Yes sorry I thought I had to do this and just noticed that it didn't work but even with this changed it doesn't work in python3. I will change the example. The point is it crashes after the first iteration in python3 and not python2.

Comment: Please make a [mcve].  The code provided should reproduce the error you describe, and it does not.  What is the definition of `newfile`  and `newfile2` for example as it is relevant to explain the error.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was enough code. The filter is just to delete any empty lines. The code and example is in https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=10GmE8B7-j3T2aaj1S4xLr4k8te23NmYY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide a reproducible example, but I reproduced the error with the following:

```py
import re

newfile = ['a']  # wasn't defined, assuming a list of strings
newfile2 = []        # wasn't defined, assuming a list

substitution_array=[
    [r"^Map From GroupLayer","Add Map GroupLayer"],[r"^Map From","Add Map Auto Layer"]
    ,[r"^\s+Papersize\s+.*",""],[r"^Set Window.*",""],[r"^Open Window.*",""]]

for row in substitution_array:
        print(row[0])
        for x in newfile:
          print(f'{x=}')
          line = re.sub(row[0],row[1],x)
          line2=filter(line.strip, line)
          print(f'{line2=}')
          newfile2.append(line2)
          print(f'{newfile2=}')
        print ("Finished: "+row[0])
        newfile=newfile2
        newfile2=[]
        print(f'{newfile=} {newfile2=}')
```

Output (comments added):

```py
^Map From GroupLayer
x='a'     # x is a string
line2=<filter object at 0x000001E3D5BAAE50> # filter() returns a iterable object in Python 3
newfile2=[<filter object at 0x000001E3D5BAAE50>] # newfile gets this object
Finished: ^Map From GroupLayer
newfile=[<filter object at 0x000001E3D5BAAE50>] newfile2=[]
^Map From
x=<filter object at 0x000001E3D5BAAE50>  # NEXT ITERATION, x is that filter object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\metolone\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    line = re.sub(row[0],row[1],x)    # then re.sub complains about it
  File "D:\dev\Python39\lib\re.py", line 210, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

What do you think `line2 = filter(line.strip,line)` does anyway?  This is saying "remove characters where line.strip(x) is true for each_character in line".  In this case `line.strip(' ')` for example will only return false if **all** the characters in the line are spaces, so if there is any variation in the line it will remain unchanged and any line with all the same character will be blanked.  The filter function will also be called x number of times for a line of length x, which is inefficient as well.  Example from Python 2:

```py
>>> line = '  \n  a '          # variation, no change
>>> filter(line.strip,line)
'  \n  a '                     
>>> line = '            '      # all spaces, blanks the line
>>> filter(line.strip,line)
''
>>> line = '   \n     '        # different kinds of whitespace, no change
>>> filter(line.strip,line)
'   \n     '
>>> line = '\n\n\n\n\n'        # all same newline, blanks line
>>> filter(line.strip,line)
''
>>> line = '\n\n \n\n'         # different kinds of whitespace, no change
>>> filter(line.strip,line)
'\n\n \n\n'
>>> line = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'  # no variation, blanks the line
>>> filter(line.strip,line)
''
```

So this looks like a bug and you may want to state what you think this is supposed to do and we can recommend a better way to do it.

Comment: What is confusing is why it shows the error in re.sub but the issue is with the filter. The full code and example file is in https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=10GmE8B7-j3T2aaj1S4xLr4k8te23NmYY

Comment: @GeorgeC See the comments in the output. The filter object is added to new file on the first pass through the loop and causes error  the NEXT time through the loop.  Also links rot. Edit your question with the minimum code and sample file to reproduce the error without additional edits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the intention of this line in your script

```py
line2=filter(line.strip, line)
```

But the difference is in behavior of `filter`:

```
Python 2
filter(function, iterable)
Construct a list from those elements of iterable for which function returns true.
If iterable is a string or a tuple, the result also has that type
```

```
Python 3
filter(function, iterable)
Construct an iterator from those elements of iterable for which function returns true.
```

In your script, in Python 2 `filter` returns string. But in Python 3 `filter` returns a `<filter object>` iterable, which is then causes the crash of `re.sub`, since `<filter object>` is not a string or bytes-like object.

The equivalent in Python 3 would be

```py
line2=''.join(filter(line.strip, line))
```

Comment: The line is to delete any blank rows when the re.sub deletes a line that's not required. I changed the filter and the process worked in python3. What was confusing is that the Traceback reported the error in the re.sub process that is at the line number given and is one line before the line2 filter.

Comment: @GeorgeC checking for `line.isspace()` seems more straightforward.